# Shared resource permission management (minimum required permission)

Tags: windows, active-directory, network-share, domain-controller

I want to grant a "tech" group access for managing the shared resources.

**Problem:** The sharing tab is not shown to them. Moreover they can not even access the shared folder list via management console.

**Diagnosis:** Obviously some user rights are missing for them. What permissions should I grant, to enable this access for that group?

*NOTE: I have already that "tech" group on my AD domain to whom I have granted access to login locally or via RDP to the domain controller machines. This enables them to perform minor administration and monitoring tasks and this part has been working fine. Now I want to add the ability to manage shared folders as well without elevating them to Domain-Admin.*

Comment: Create the shared resource as part of a DFS Namespace and [delegate management permissions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754770.aspx) for that namespace

Comment: It might be controllable via permissions on the registry key `HKLM\SYSTEM\Services\LanmanServer\Shares` -- I believe this is normally Read/Write for SYSTEM/Administrators and Read for Users.  If anything, at least you might be able to *deny* permissions to this.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen: Thanks, for the idea, I didn't even think of migrating to DFS. (May be a later time I could)

Comment: @jimbobmcgee: Thanks, sounds like a good idea, I should give it a try

Comment: @jimbobmcgee: It was a very near hit. I did that, but it didn't enable the sharing tab. However I saw that "server operators" already have that permission. Adding the "tech" to the "server operators" group did enable the sharing tab. I wonder what other permissions the server operators are granted that enable them this feature.